# How to catch if google maps infowindow if it overlays other?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have a `polyline` on which i need to show each points coordinates, but the problem is that each info-window overlays other so i decided to draw only those info-windows which doesnt overlay others, but don't have any idea how to catch it...

Currently i have

```
    window.onload = function() {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var coordinates = [];

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID});

        for (i = 0, len = points.point.length; i < len; i++) {
            var tmp_coor = new google.maps.LatLng(points.point[i].lat, points.point[i].lon);

            coordinates.push(tmp_coor);
            bounds.extend(tmp_coor);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: points.point[i].lat + ', ' + points.point[i].lon,
                maxWidth: 120
            });

            infowindow.setPosition(tmp_coor);

            infowindow.open(map);
        }

        var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: coordinates,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 1.0,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            editable: false
        });

        polyline.setMap(map);

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

It creates [image]

So maybe someone has any suggestions on this problem?

Comment: Yikes, that is a lot of infowindows!  Even if you only output them so they don't overlay each other.  If you *need* to show all the coordinates, could you just output them as some kind of list beneath the map?  Alternatively, have the infowindow appear on hover over the polyline, for that coordinates only

Comment: @duncan nope, i need it on each.

Comment: One problem is going to be that the size of the infowindows is decided dynamically based on its content.  So if your coordinates are (0,0) that infowindow will be smaller than one for (-89.99999,-179.9999)

Comment: @duncan so there isn't any way to get position of current `infowindow` div?

Comment: Well you have getPosition() on the InfoWindow class, but that just gives you the lat/lng coordinates!